# Swift: how to access multiple UISwitches that were created programmatically with only one function

Tags: swift, uiswitch

I have created a table where on each row there is a name and a UISwitch button. The number of rows is not fixed (and as a result nor is the number of UIswitches) and it depends on user entries.
I have managed to give a tag to each UISwitch but I don't know how to access them from the @IBAction func

Code

```
import UIKit

class Katw2ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



var perasmenoList = [String]()
var listaApotelesmatwn = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var katw2Tableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var debugLabel: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.katw2Tableview.dataSource = self
    self.katw2Tableview.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return perasmenoList.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    var switchView = UISwitch()
    cell.accessoryView = switchView
    switchView.tag = indexPath.row
    switchView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("switchChanged"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    cell.textLabel!.text = self.perasmenoList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

@IBAction func switchChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
//Do things
}


}
```

Comment: Here's an [example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41761/how-can-i-condense-several-ibaction-methods-in-a-class-with-a-delegate) of doing exactly this sort of thing.  The example is written in Objective-C, but if you just read it, it should be pretty easy to translate into Swift, even if you don't know Objective-C at all.

Comment: `let tag = sender.tag` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

from another post I just found from  nhgrif's link, all that was missing was a semicolon in "switchChanged:"

```
switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PIN.switchChanged(_:)),    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

it works now

Answer (score 0):

You can access tag property using `sender.tag` in your `switchChanged` action.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to manage mutable `Array` or Mutable `Dictionary`,

suppose we are using Mutable Dictionary, which stores value like

```
@{ 
   @"1" : 1 ,
   @"5" : 1 ,
   @"8" : 1 ,
}
```

In this case we have 3 switches in ON state, at indexes 1, 5 and 8.

Suppose User tap on switch of Index 6,
in this case "`switchChanged()`" will be called.

In this method, get the index of row by using the `sender.tag`, you will get `Int` value, convert it into `String` and check if value for that index is available in dictionary or not.

If value is available, means it was in ON state before, now it is OFF by User. So in this case remove that `{<key>,<value>}` pair from dictionary.

If value is not available, means it was in OFF state before, now it is ON by User. So in this case add that `{<key>,<value>}` pair into dictionary.

In `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method, check the same for `indexpath.row` variable, and turn `UISwitch` ON or OFF.